# Show that sets are equal

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, symmetric-functions

Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_n\}$ be sets over a finite field $F$ with $p=char(F)>2$. Assume

$$x_1^k+x_2^k+...+x_n^k=y_1^k+y_2^k+...+y_n^k,\ 1\leq k\leq n$$

I wanna show that $X=Y$.

Comment: Are you discussing sets or multisets? Are repetitions allowed?

Comment: @Vladimir no, I am discussing sets. Let me mention that in the question

Comment: Maybe instead of changing your question every time it gets pointed out that it's false, you figure out what your real question is and ask that?  Constantly moving the goal posts is not appreciated.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy the problem was that I initially I wanted to prove this for $n \neq 2^k\ mod p$, but assumed it might be true in general

Comment: @RandomUser And now your condition doesn't prevent $n\equiv 0\bmod p$ (since $2$ is always a unit modulo an odd prime), and there are counterexamples there, as well.  Run my same counterexample but on three-element sets, instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard notations $e_k=\sum_{A\subset \{1,\dots,n\}, |A|=k} \prod_{i\in A} x_i$, with the conventions $e_0=1$ and $e_m=0$ for $m>n$; $p_k=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k$.

If $n=p$, the statement is true if you require your conditions for all $k$, not just $k\le n$.

Indeed, Newton's identities say that
 $$
ke_k=\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1} p_ie_{k-i} 
 $$
for all $k$
Of course for $k=p$ we shall have an issue with finding $e_p$ from the $p$-th equation. But, if you look at the $p+1$-st equation, you can recover $e_p$ from it unless $p_1=0$, or if $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_{m-1}=0$ and $p_m\ne0$, then the $m+p$-th equation will give you $e_p$, the $m+p+1$st equation will give you $e_{p+1}$ etc. Thus, you recover all the elementary symmetric polynomials unless $p_k=0$ for all $k$. In this case, Newton's identities tell us that $e_k=0$ for $k$ not divisible by $p$, so the polynomial 
 $$
(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)
 $$
is a polynomial in $x^p$. Over a finite field of characteristic $p$, we have $g(x^p)=(h(x))^p$ for some $h(x)$, since every element is a $p$-th power. Thus, there will be repetitions among $x_i$, which is what you do not allow.

Originally, I claimed this for all $n$, but as noted in comments, for $n>p$ one has to be more careful.

In addition, for $n=3=p$, the formula given by @zibadawatimmy [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75017/discussion-between-zibadawa-timmy-and-randomuser) can be made explicit: $(0,1,-1)$ and $(-1+i,i,1+i)$ have the same first three power sums in $\mathbb{F}_9=\mathbb{F}_3[i]/(i^2+1)$. Indeed: 
\begin{gather}
0+1+(-1)=0=(-1+i)+i+(1+i),\\
0^2+1^2+(-1)^2=-1=(-1+i)^2+i^2+(1+i)^2,\\
0^3+1^3+(-1)^3=0=(-1+i)^3+i^3+(1+i)^3.
\end{gather}
Thus, it is not sufficient to ask for these formulas for $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: It would not harm to explain what are the $p_i$ and $e_i$...

Comment: Alternatively, you can find a polynomial that vanishes at all but one value among those occurring in $X$ and $Y$, and look at the corresponding linear combination of power sums.

Comment: @vladdimir consider $F_9$ and $n=5$. then in 4th equation there are two unknowns, $e_3$ and $e_4$, so I can't recover them. The problem is that this system of equations has many solutions in terms of $e_k$'s, I just wanna show that the corresponding polynomial of only one of them has $n$ distinct solutions.

Comment: yes you are right. The way as presented the claim works for $n=p$ though. I re-wrote the answer, and also made the example of @zibadawatimmy explicit.

Comment: @Seva that would be a valid comment on MSE, not MO, I believe.

Comment: Agree with Seva.  Even if these notations are standard in symmetric functions community, there are many absolutely normal people who do not know about it, or use other letters, like sigma's for e's.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you for the feedback. I suppose both you and Seva can edit the post and add the definition, if you believe that it is important.

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample: Let $\mathbf{F}_4 = \{0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1\}$, take $X = \{0,\alpha+1\}$ and $Y = \{1,\alpha\}$. The sums obviously match, and we have

$0^2 + (\alpha+1)^2 = \alpha = 1^2 + \alpha^2$.

Hmmm... If we go to the next higher power sum, though, we have

$0^3 + (\alpha+1)^3 = 1 \ne 0 = 1^3 + \alpha^3$.

**Edit:** Oops, somehow I missed the requirement to have characteristic more than $2$. To salvage my honor, here's a counterexample in $\mathbb{F}_{p^p}$ with $|X|=|Y|=p$ disjoint:

Take $X = \{0, 1, ..., p-1\}$, so $X$ is the set of solutions to the equation $x^p=x$, and take $Y$ to be the set of solutions to the equation $y^p = y+1$ ($Y$ is a shift of $X$, so the elements of $Y$ are distinct). For $k < p$, the power sums match by Newton's identities, while for $k = p$ we have

$\sum x_i^p = \sum x_i = \sum y_i = \sum (y_i + 1) = \sum y_i^p$.

In fact, by the same argument, the first $k$ such that the power sum differs is $k = 2p-1$.

Comment: He specified characteristic greater than two, though it's still false (just use $\mathbb{F}_9$).

Comment: Ah, I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. You can easily check it in GAP, for example.  Here's a way to get a counterexample in $\mathbb{F}_9$ for $n=4$.

`q:=9; n:=4;`
`FF:=GF(q);`
`sets:=Tuples(FF,n);;`
`sets:=Set(List(sets,Set));;`

`sets:=Filtered(sets,x->Length(x)=n);;`

`PowerSums := function(vals,m)`

`return(List([1..m],k->Sum(List(vals,t->t^k))));`

`end;`

`S:=First(sets,x->ForAny(sets,y->(not x=y) and PowerSums(x,n)=PowerSums(y,n)));`

This returns a four element set, and we can find the other one similarly.

`T:=First(sets,y->(not y=S) and PowerSums(S,n)=PowerSums(y,n));`

We also get examples for $n=3$ by just changing that one value at the start and rerunning.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention in the question, $n\neq 0\ mod\ char(F)$. Will edit$

Comment: @RandomUser That doesn't affect my counterexample in the slightest.  Characteristic here is 3, $n$ is 4.

Comment: In your counterexample, your sets share an element. It's almost plausible it's true for disjoint sets $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @RandomUser You have an alarming inability to compute congruences.  This uses the field of 9 elements.  Which has characteristic 3.  What is $4\mod 3$?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy sorry, this is kind of funny, there was a typo.

Comment: @zeb No, that's also false in general.  You can find disjoint $S,T$ for $n=4$ in $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ (though you can't in the field of 9 elements, so maybe as long as $n$ is not too small this is true).

Comment: @zeb this should be true if $n\neq 2^k\ mod\ p$. I forgot to mention that in my initial question. my bad (

Comment: @RandomUser Still false.  Now you don't disallow $n\equiv 0\bmod p$, and then I can just use 3-element sets.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy For $n=0\ mod\ p$ in $F_9$ there are no such sets, I checked with computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75017/discussion-between-zibadawa-timmy-and-randomuser).

Answer (score 2):

Let me prove that if for two sets of $n$ distinct numbers $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ the sums of $k$th powers for $k=1,\ldots,2n-1$ are the same, then $X=Y$, irrespectively of the ground field. This shows that the example of @zeb given in his answer (for $n=p$ over a field of characteristic $p$) is, in a sense, optimal.

For that, let us take set $X$ and consider the Newton identities number $n$, \ldots, $2n-1$: 
\begin{aligned}
ne_n&=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}p_k e_{n-k},\\
 0&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1}p_k e_{n+1-k},\\
 \ldots \\
 0&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} (-1)^{k-1}p_k e_{2n-1-k},\\
\end{aligned} 
with the usual convention $e_0=1$, $e_m=0$ for $m>n$. Given the power sums $p_1, p_2, \ldots$, these formulas are $n$ linear equations with $n$ unknowns $e_1, \ldots, e_n$, whose matrix of coefficients is easily seen to have the entry $i,j$ equal to $(-1)^{i+j-1}p_{i+j-2}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th power sum of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, including $p_0=n$ (this accounts for the term $ne_n$ in the first equation). Changing the variables $x_i\to -x_i$ and multiplying the matrix by $-1$, we get the matrix whose entry $i,j$ equal to $p_{i+j-2}$. This matrix is, by a direct inspection, equal to $VV^T$, where $V$ is the Vandermonde matrix, so its determinant is $\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2$. Thus, for pairwise distinct $x_i$, this system has the only solution for $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. Clearly, the elementary symmetric functions determine the set $X$ uniquely.

Comment: @RandomUser zeb gave an example (for $n=p$) where the smallest $k$ where the power sums differ is $k=2p-1$. This argument I typed ensures that if all the power sums from $1$ to $2p-1$ were the same, then the sets coincide.

Comment: sorry, missed that, and deleted my comment before your reply. thanks again